# Can I update the owner id of a Contact using LINQ?

Tags: linq, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm using CRM 2011, and attempting to update the OwnerId of contact using this code:

```
var crmContext = new CustomCrmContext(service);

var contact = crmContext.Contact.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.Id == id);
contact.OwnerId.Id= newOwnerId;
crmContext.UpdateObject(contact);
crmContext.SaveChanges();
```

I don't get any errors, however, the ownerId never updates in the database.  I am able to update other attributes, but I'm just wondering if maybe the OwnerId is special and you have to use OrganizationRequest("Assign")?  If so, where is this documented so I know what other attributes I cannot update?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The owner of a record cannot be modified with an update. You have to send a [AssignRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.assignrequest.aspx) instead.

```
// Create the Request Object and Set the Request Object's Properties
var request = new AssignRequest
{
    Assignee = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, _newOwnerId),
    Target = new EntityReference(Account.EntityLogicalName,  _accountId)
};


// Execute the Request
_service.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Is there a list of other properties that require a specific request object, or is owner the only one?

Comment: The status is another one - I think the CRM generates two classes per entity with the pattern SetStateAccountRequest and SetStateAccountResponse.

Comment: As usual, no warning from the SDK when this fails.

Comment: @Ryan it is simply filtered out because the owner is not an *updateable* field