# Change owner of a workflow

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm-2011

I am creating a linqpad script where I want to achieve the following:

1) Assign all draft and active workflows to myself
2) Activate all the draft workflows

My problem is that if I attempt to change the owner of an active workflow I get an error saying I cannot update the workflow because it's active. If I try deactivate then it errors saying I'm not the owner (hence I'm not allowed). It's confusing because I can easily do this via the UI.

The code I'm using to update owner:

```
var systemUser = 
var workflow = ...;
workflow.OwnerId = systemUser.ToEntityReference();
UpdateObject(workflow);
SaveChanges(); //exception: Cannot update a published workflow definition
```

The code I'm using to deactivate workflow:

```
var request = SetStateRequest {
    EntityMoniker = workflow.ToEntityReference(),
    State = new OptionSetValue(/*state value*/),
    Status = new OptionSetValue(/* status value*/)
};
service.Execute(request); //exception: The workflow cannot be published or unpublished by someone who is not its owner
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change the owner of a record with an update. You have to use the `AssignRequest` to change the owner. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7746205/315862) at [Can I update the owner id of a Contact using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746046/315862)