# Dynamics 2011: Setting Owner of Activity record

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying create Activity record in Dynamics 2011 with owner name set as "test_user". Instead below code is taking credential which is used to access Dynamics API. Is there any way to impersonate "test_user" user without passing his password? Thank you.

```csharp
string TargetCrmService = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TargetCrmService"];
string UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
string Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

Uri organizationUri = new Uri("http://CRMDEV/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc");
Uri homeRealmUri = null;
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();

credentials.UserName.UserName = Domain + "\\" + UserName;
credentials.UserName.Password = Password;

OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);

var _userId = (from u in orgProxy.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
           where u.FullName == "Kevin Cook"
           select u.SystemUserId.Value).FirstOrDefault();

IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)orgProxy;
_service.CallerId = _userId;


try
{
    //Entity activity = new Entity("activitypointer");

    Entity activity = new Entity("appointment");
    activity["subject"] = "Test Meeting 1";
    activity["description"] = "Test Description";
    activity["scheduledstart"] = DateTime.Now;
    activity["scheduledend"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
    activity["createdbyname"] = "test_user";
    activity["modifiedbyname"] = "test_user";
    activity["createdbyname"] = "test_user";
    activity["owneridname"] = "test_user";

    Guid id = _service.Create(activity);
    Console.WriteLine("id: " + id);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

**Modified Code**

Based on example on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx

```
var _userId = (from u in orgProxy.CreateQuery<SystemUser>()
           where u.FullName == "Kevin Cook"
           select u.SystemUserId.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two methods of setting the owenr id of an entity in CRM.

1. Use the [AssignRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746046/can-i-update-the-owner-id-of-a-contact-using-linq) to update the record after it is created.
2. Use [impersonation with the OrganizationServiceProxy, CallerId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309629.aspx) to use the particular user you'd like to be the owner when it's created.  You don't need their password to do impersonation, just their CRM SystemUserId

Comment: Thanks Daryl, I tried  impersonation with the OrganizationServiceProxy, CallerId but its throwing this compilation error: Error 1 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy' does not contain a definition for 'CreateQuery' and no extension method 'CreateQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Why are you doing a CreateQuery, and not using the code above?  You'll need to post your code...

Comment: I think I am missing something here. I updated my code above.

Comment: I got it! My bad. I suppose to use OrganizationServiceContext instead of OrganizationServiceProxy. Thanks Daryl for your help.