# ETL Software, can't retrieve owner of a contact

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, data-migration

First question, with my ETL software, I could map all GM contact fields and migrate them to MCRM contact entity. The only field I can't is the owner (the owner is then always the creator of the contact).

I found that they are privileges on this entity fields [prvAssignContact](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328465.aspx).

Is their a trick to remove this security, or a thing I could do through the SDK Toolkit I just started to use yesterday?

On SO, I found this topic, [Can I update the owner id of a Contact using LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746046/can-i-update-the-owner-id-of-a-contact-using-linq) but simply don't know if it will be useful for me and if yes, where to put that code.

P:S: I definitely have to do it alone... so I would enjoy user-friendly advices!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Guido's answer, if you use [impersonation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334744.aspx) on your IOrganizationService, it will automatically set the owner to the impersonated user.

Comment: sorry, it seems I have to use the SDK toolkit to do this and I'm not that far!

Answer (score 5):

Will be useful to know which ETL you are using, however there is an important thing to consider when you do data migration.
If you are creating a new record, to specify the owner is enough to set the field with an EntityReference

```cs
        Entity contact = new Entity("contact");
        contact["firstname"] = "John";
        Guid ownerId = new Guid("BFC777ED-5E79-E111-8489-00166D63156F");
        contact["ownerid"] = new EntityReference("systemuser", ownerId);
        service.Create(contact);
```

If you are updating a contact you need to use the AssignRequest as explained in the other topic

```cs
        Guid contactId = new Guid("90F8889F-EB95-E781-8417-000C44420CBC");
        Guid newOwnerId = new Guid("BFCAA4ED-5E79-E781-8349-00155BB3156F");
        AssignRequest assignRequest = new AssignRequest
        {
            Assignee = new EntityReference("systemuser", newOwnerId),
            Target = new EntityReference("contact", contactId)
        };
        service.Execute(assignRequest);
```

Comment: hello, I am using StarFish ETL, I can use C # or vbscript to make a function field on the owner, thanks if you could bring me some details!